# Autofac test all registered types can be resolved

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a bunch of types registered with Autofac and some of the dependencies are rather deep.  Is there a built in way to test that I can resolve all registered types? I want to fail fast at application startup, and not several minutes later part way in.

This is what I'm currently doing, and it seems to work, but I still wonder if there isn't a better way.

```
    public void VerifyAllRegistrations()
    {
        foreach (IComponentRegistration registration in _container.ComponentRegistrations)
        {
            bool isNewInstance;
            registration.ResolveInstance(_container, new Parameter[0], new Disposer(), out isNewInstance);
        }            
    }

    private class Disposer : IDisposer
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // no-op
        }

        public void AddInstanceForDisposal(IDisposable instance)
        {
            instance.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autofac doesn't offer anything to that effect - because Autofac creates components in response to ResolveInstance, you're going to be faced with constructor side-effects etc.

Integration testing is the best way to address this.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.ConventionTests/releases/tag/2.1.0